# How many unstated reward triggers, like Getting all Eavesdropping and Cameras, are there?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

Are there rewards for completing all the Challenges, or finding all the Las Catrinas murals, or any other event?

If there are, what's the rewards? I need ~200K more OverCharge to just buy all the guns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, only some collections get you money and OverCharge. Getting all the High Points isn't one of them. That only gets you the Killer Jacket, and removing the maps from purchase.